# Import from url question -- "Cannot import data as Graph6 format"

Tags: import, warning-messages, html, xml

When I import url, there will show the folling message:

> "Cannot import data as Graph6 format"

The codes as following:

```
Import["http://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/mksc.14.3.G6","XMLObject"]
```

But the another url will work:

```
 Import["http://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/mksc.14.3.G20","XMLObject"]
```

I don't know why it happend, I can visit the website directly. I guess the **".G6"** is the problem, but I don't know how the solve it.

I change "XMLObject" to "HTML" (by Szabolcs), but the return datas is different with "XMLObject".

[image]

Comment: Note that this is HTML, not XML. Trying to import as XML would fail.

Answer (score 4):

To make this work, you need to specify the format.  There is no `"XMLObject"` [format](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListingOfAllFormats.html).  `"XMLObject"` is an *import element* for the `"HTML"` and `"XML"` (and perhaps some other) *formats*.  Thus when you only specify "XMLObject", Mathematica is still trying to auto-detect the format.  In this case, it will try to import the file as the Graph6 format, which won't work for a HTML document.

Specify the format explicitly as `"HTML"` and also specify the import element, i.e. that you want the result as an `"XMLObjct"`.

```
Import["http://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/mksc.14.3.G6", {"HTML", "XMLObject"}]
```

---

Note that this is exactly the same mistake as using `Import["somefile", "Data"]`, which is unfortunately all too commonly seen on this site.  `"Data"` isn't a format either, and when you use it, you are betting on the success of format detection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I changed the question, and add another url, it will work. I don't know why.

Comment: @zongxian Because it doesn't end in `.g6`, so the result of the auto-detection is not the Graph6 format. As I said in the answer, if you leave it up to Mathematica to guess the format, it might or it might not get it right.  You are relying on luck.

Comment: I tried your method, but the return contents is different, I will add a image in the question.

Comment: @zongxian You did not read the answer carefully and did something else than what I suggested.

Comment: I know your mean is there is no "XMLObject", I use it is wrong, but how can I know the website is a "html" or "XML", MMa auto check it and return datas, but if I use "html", it return the different contents with "XMLObject", as I am a new user, so I don't knon how to get the same content as use the wrong parameter of "XMLObject".

Comment: If it's a website, then it's HTML.